# Doubletapped on Grid

Tags: c#, xaml, grid, winrt-xaml

I have created a Doubletapped event for Grid. That is whenever a Doubletap event is generated on anywhere in the grid a popup should show up. However the popup does not show up if I do double tap on the grid, it shows up if I double tap on the Listview which is part of the grid.

Can anyone please help as to what is wrong here and how can I generated a popup when the user double taps on grid and not just on listview.

```
<Grid Margin="0" Doubletapped="Grid_on_Doubletapped_1"

 <ListView x:Name="ItemListView" \>

<\Grid>
```

Thanks,
Padamkar

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the grid is not actually as large as you think. Try changing the background to verify.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the background and its well beyond the list view. One thing what i noticed was if I change the grid background color the Double tap works when tapped on the grid but with transparent background it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am trying with Microsoft Surface its working fine for me .I have written the following code

```
 <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" DoubleTapped="Grid_DoubleTapped_1">
        <ListView Background="Beige" Height="400" Width="400">

        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

then in the code behind

```
private void Grid_DoubleTapped_1(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("double Tapped");
            msg.ShowAsync();
        }
```

I have tried with Microsoft surface,its working fine for double tapped